# Defining set-theoretic section on finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be a finite abelian group and $\cdot 2:A \to 2A$ the square-epimorphism.
Let $\{ a_i\}$ be a minimal generating set for $A$, s.t. $2a_i \neq 0$. I want to define a set-theoretic section $s:2A \to A$, s.t. $s(2a_i)=a_i$. Is there a possibility to extend this multiplicatively somehow, so that $s (\sum_i r_i 2 a_i) = \sum_i r_i a_i  $ for $0 \leq r_i  < |2a_i|$, by choosing particular words on letters $a_i$ for every element $2a \in 2A$?

Comment: If there were such section, $2A$ would be a sub factor of $A$. I think this is the case if and only if $A$ is of odd order if and only if $A=2A$.

Comment: oops, I meant set-theoretic section

Comment: Okay, I don't think I get the difference between group-theoretic section and set-theoretic section with the condition you added. Maybe an example with a cyclic $2$-group of this section would be useful or $\mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/4$

Comment: The condition does not imply $s(2a_i)s(-2a_i)=s(0)$, since the equation holds only for $r_i$ strictly less than $|2a_i|$. For example, if $2A= \bigoplus_i\, \langle 2a_i\rangle$ this is always well-defined.

Comment: In general, I do not think you can, because all involutions in $A$ are mapped to zero. So if you have involutions in your minimal set, you are in trouble. Perhaps if you have only one involution in your minimal set, you can define $s(0)$ to be just that involution, but with more involutions, I do not see a way out.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti So would you think it is possible when $2a_i \neq 0$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$I was writing up a comment, but since it was a bit too long, I have expanded it into an answer.

The kernel of $\cdot 2$ would be $K = \Set{ a \in A : 2 a = 0 }$, and then $\cdot 2$ yields an isomorphism $A / K \to 2 A$. Assuming none of the $a_{i}$ is in $K$, $\cdot 2$ restricts to a bijection on the set
$$
B = \Set{ \sum_{i} r_{i} a_{i} : 0 \le r_{i} < N_{i}/2},
$$
where $N_{i}$ is the order of $a_{i}$, so that $N_{i}/2$ is the order of $2 a_{i}$. This is simply because if
$$
\sum_{i} 2 r_{i} a_{i} = \sum_{i} 2 s_{i} a_{i},
$$
with $0 \le r_{i} , s_{i} < N_{i}$, we have $2 r_{i} = 2 s_{i}$ and thus $r_{i} = s_{i}$.

So, yes, you can construct your $s$ this way, as the inverse of this bijection.

This works in general to get a map $s$ such that composing $s$ and then $\cdot 2$ you have the identity on $2 A$, only it will not have in general the property $s(2 a_{i}) = a_{i}$ you asked for, in case $a_{i}$ is an involution.

Comment: Thanks, but $\sum_i 2r_i a_i = \sum_i 2s_i a_i$ does not imply $2r_i = 2s_i$, the $a_i$'s are generators, but we don't have $A = \bigoplus_i \langle a_i\rangle$.. also, $|a_i|=N_i/gcd(N_i,2)$

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed you had $A = \bigoplus_i \langle a_i\rangle$.